# SQLITE3 for dummies - solved (sort of)

Tags: shell, cygwin, sqlite

I'm trying to learn the SQLite with "sqlite3 -interactive" shell (under Cygwin). For supposedly all legal reasons the sqlite3 shows the following prompt every time I forget to add a semicolon at the end of commands:

`...>`

Is there an intelligent way out of this situation, other than hitting the Cntrl-C and restarting shell?

### Edit #1

I obviously tried adding the semicolon but this doesn't seem to work:

`>sqlite3 -interactive test.db`  
`SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22`  
`Enter ".help" for instructions`  
`Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"`  
`sqlite> insert into T1 values('Aaa ', 231 )`  
`...> ;`  
`...>`

### Edit #2

Bugs of the SQLite3 for Cygwin? It suddenly worked for me for a couple of times and then it stopped...

`sqlite>` 
`sqlite> insert into T1 values('Aaa ', 232 )` 
`...> ;` 
`sqlite> insert into T1 values('Aaa ', 232 )` 
`...> ;` 
`sqlite> insert into T1 values('Aaa ', 232 )` 
`...> ;` 
`...> ;` 
`...>`

### Solution:

Avoid the Cygwin's SQLite and use a pre-compiled for Win SQLite3 shell. Everything works, including the command line history.

Too bad the SQLite3 that came with Cygwin doesn't work as expected... :)

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Add the semicolon?

Comment: Not forgetting a semicolon is always a good idea. What should I do if I already missed one?

Comment: "SQLite3 for Cygwin" How come you're not using a native client?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Not sure what you mean. I'm using the SQLite that came with the cygwin (/usr/local/bin/sqlite3)

Comment: http://sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: I assumed the one that is built for Windows doesn't work with Cygwin: (http://superuser.com/questions/253059/using-sqlite3-with-cygwin?rq=1)

Comment: Irrelevant. You don't need it to work with Cygwin; Cygwin has its own.

Comment: Sorry, I can't vote for your help. MY "reputation" is too low to do anything but asking silly questions :). Thanks a lot, pal

Answer (score 3):

It's waiting for you to finish the statement. A semicolon will finish the statement. So... type the semicolon and press Enter.

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't seem to work. I've updated the question with the logs.

Comment: Works fine here. `sqlite> insert into T1 values('Aaa ', 231 )`
`...> ;`
`sqlite> `

Comment: Very strange. Seems like glitches of my cygwin/sqlite3... See Edit #2.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Avoid the Cygwin's SQLite and use a pre-compiled for Win SQLite3 shell. Everything works, including the command line history. I'm currently using the Cygwin "1.7.15(0.260/5/3) 2012-05-09".

Too bad the SQLite3 that came with Cygwin doesn't work as expected... :)

Many thanks to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams for helping with this